# JMeter - Performance Testing - Third Party Backend GET Response

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am currently working on load testing an application, where the users can create orders. Once the order is created, the request reaches the Middleware which triggers a scheduler. From the scheduler, the GET Status reaches a 3rd Party API and the Response is stored at the Backend (DB). The GET Status response can only be seen on the Backend and it will not be visible to the User Interface. Please help on How to record this GET Status Response at the Backend using latest version of Jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler for reading information from the database

1. Download [JDBC Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for the database you're using and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the driver
3. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) element and specify [database URL](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-url-format), credentials and [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) name
4. In the JDBC Request sampler set the same thread pool name as in the point 3 and create an [SQL Select query](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) to fetch the response from the database. If you will need the response later on [it can be stored into a JMeter Variable](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter/)